# VBA (Excel): Get last non-empty row in a Range

Tags: vba, excel, row, cells

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains data similar to the following:
[image]

I want to do a certain set of operations for each category for each of the names. I am guaranteed to have an empty cell before each new set of categories (but not necessarily the names), so when I iterate over the names, I do the following to find out what the last category row is:

```
rowNum = sheetVariable.Cells(theName.Row + 1, 2).End(xlDown).Row
```

This works great except that if there is only **one** category for a name (such as for `name4` in the example image), it hops down to the next category of the next name.

Is there a way to do this so that it also works for the case where there is only one category row for a person?

Comment: Make that an answer and I'll accept it. It's not as elegant as I had hoped for, but that does the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if

```
sheetVariable.Cells(theName.Row + 2, 2)
```

is empty: if not then you can use the `.End(xlDown)` approach, otherwise the last row is `theName.Row + 1`